# How to create new Constraints in TSP with GLPK

Tags: ampl, glpk

I used this example [TSP](http://trac.astrometry.net/browser/trunk/projects/archetypes/glpk-4.31/examples/tsp.mod?rev=9312) for calculate the tours.

But how to create new constraints?

Imagine a simple example, I have 5 cities, but there is no road in every city, so I want to eliminate without road sections with new restrictions, how I do it in GLPK?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a TSP problem in [AMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL) (which is a superset of GNU MathProg used by Glpk), taken from [here](http://tomopt.com/ampl/service/tsp.mod):

```
set S ordered;
param n := card {S};

set SS := 0 .. (2**n - 1);

set POW {k in SS} := {i in S: (k div 2**(ord(i)-1)) mod 2 = 1};


set LINKS := {i in S, j in S: ord(i) < ord(j)};

param cost {LINKS} >= 0;
var X {LINKS} binary;

minimize TotCost: sum {(i,j) in LINKS} cost[i,j] * X[i,j];

subj to Tour {i in S}: 
   sum {(i,j) in LINKS} X[i,j] + sum {(j,i) in LINKS} X[j,i] = 2;

subj to SubtourElim {k in SS diff {0,2**n-1}}:
   sum {i in POW[k], j in S diff POW[k]: (i,j) in LINKS} X[i,j] +
   sum {i in POW[k], j in S diff POW[k]: (j,i) in LINKS} X[j,i] >= 2;


data;

set S := a b c d ;

param cost:  a   b   c   d :=
        a    .  43  21  19
        b    .   .  21  12
        c    .   .   .  39
        d    .   .   .   . ;
```

If you don't have links between every city, you can model it by providing only existing links in the `LINKS` set, for example:

```
# model:
set LINKS;
# data:
set LINKS := (a b) (b d);
```